# Change class name color in visual studio

Tags: colors, visual-studio-2010

I've been looking for a way to change the color of class names in visual studio but I can't find. I've tried User Type - Class but it doesn't change anything. However other categories like plain text, comments, c++ functions change color fine.

In red: The color I'd like to change:

[image]

Also as an extra question: is there a way to change the color of class functions only ? (Circled blue in the image above)

Comment: [Visual Studio, How to change the color of classes?](//stackoverflow.com/a/31014752)

Comment: Yes I already tried that but it didn't work. I've also tried restarting vs after changing the color but it didn't work either.

Comment: Did you also read the comments to that answer?

Comment: Yes I did, I tried some solutions but they don't work